# CodeIgniter .htaccess Affecting Forms

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, codeigniter, post

Removing the index.php from URLs have caused my form pages to not receive POST data.

This form is on the URL http://localhost/guestbook/

The following form tag works:

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/index.php/guestbook/">
```

This (and leaving it blank) does not work:

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/guestbook/">
```

The first one does work fine, but it changes the URL the user sees to the action url - I would like to keep the index.php out of the URL.

This is my htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1/ [L]
```

How could I get the form to submit to the rewritten URL?

Comment: Use relative path <form method="post" action="/guestbook">

Comment: @Tpojka That did not work either.

Comment: Are other controllers work without `index.php` regardless POST action?

Answer (score 0):

in config file change it

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to this

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

may be work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help 
Htaccess file will be :

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</ifmodule>
```

And make changes in Confg file `application/config.php`
Make `$config` Blank

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

AND IN HTACCESS FILE put following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```